# Access java jTextField from main method

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, applet, awt

I've created GUI in swing using netbeans, in it, the structure hirarcy of the java file is below,

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame
    private void initComponents
-->         jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();

    public static void main
         // one thread 
-->              jTextField1.setText("abc");
```

so while setting jTextField1's value in the thread Inside the main Function, the error occurs **"Non-static variable jTextField1  cannot be reference from static context"**.

I want to access **only** that particular **jTextField1's** value, i dont want to create a new TextField object inside the main function.

i'm able to access the textfiled from a button's click event,

and same error occurs in jList1 while adding/removing items in it, so any solution to **access that** control inside the main() function ?

i've basic knowledge of java and i'm switching a project in vb6 to java...

Comment: You should access `jTextField1` using the instance variable of `NewJFrame` in `main` body...As main is the static method and can access only the class (static) variables and methods.

Comment: One question: Why would you call `setText` from JTextField in `main`, and not in i.e. `init` method. Just curious...

Comment: it's just because it client server based application so the thread is running in main method, and i want to access the textfield inside the thread ..

Comment: So why don't you make a method (like `public void doThreadStuff(){....}`) and put your thread logic inside of it and then call that method in main (like: `NewJFrame njf = new NewJFrame()`; and then `njf.doThreadStuff();` ).

Answer (score 1):

Error says it all -> **Non-static variable jTextField1 cannot be reference from static context**.

`jTextfield1` is non static and in order to access it from an static context(here `main` method) you need an object reference of the class.

try this:

```
NewJFrame obj = new NewJFrame();
obj.jTextField1.setText("abc");
```

instance fields should be accessed using object

Comment: I want to access only that particular jTextField1's value that object is already created, i dont want to create a new TextField object inside the main function.

Comment: @BhaveshGangani you are not creating a new textfield here. if you want that then just make that jTextField1 static

Comment: i've made a separate class for the main function and used a setter in the GUI class and accessed it with `NewJFrame obj = new NewJFrame();` `obj.TextSetter("abc");` , the program runs but but it causes  "java.lang.NullPointerException" error in the debugger.

Comment: @BhaveshGangani can we see the body of `TextSetter()`

Comment: `public void setTexter(String s ) {
        jTextField1.setText(s);
    }`

Comment: @BhaveshGangani if you have done this ` jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();` before calling `setTexter("abc");` that should have workded

Answer (score 0):

You can either change `jTextField1` to static or instantiate it inside `main`

Move this line:

```
JTextField jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
```

to `main` function.

Answer (score 0):

Thought about reading up on the swing package? It's not hard to learn enough to make basic windows and textfields and interact with them yourself, instead of using netbeans for it.

A tip could be separating your GUI in a class, make getters and setters in it. Create a GUI-class object in another class and instantiate it... then reach through it and use the setter methods to manipulate textfields and such. There's many ways to do it, but I think you need to read up on it in my opinion.